# How to compare previous node element value with current node element value in foreach in xslt

Tags: xslt

How we can compare Previous Item1 value with the current item1 value with in for each loop in xslt.can you please advise me.below is the input.

input:

```
<t>
<Items>
<Item1>24</Item1>

</Items>

<Items>
<Item1>25</Item1>

</Items>

<Items>
<Item1>25</Item1>

</Items>

</t>
```

output:

```
<t>

<xsl:for-each select="Items">

 <xsl:if previos Item1 != current Item1><!-- compare previous item1 with current Item1 -->





 </xsl:for-each>
 </t>
```

Comment: You haven't provided the wanted result from the transformation -- are you trying to dedup the `Item1` elements?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a general solution for the general case when the items in the node-list aren't siblings** (and may even belong to different documents):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Items/Item1">
      <xsl:with-param name="pNodeList" select="Items/Item1"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item1">
   <xsl:param name="pNodeList"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()[not(. = $pNodeList[$vPos -1])]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<t>
    <Items>
        <Item1>24</Item1>
    </Items>
    <Items>
        <Item1>25</Item1>
    </Items>
    <Items>
        <Item1>25</Item1>
    </Items>
</t>
```

**the wanted, (assumed) correct result is produced:**

```
<Item1>24</Item1>
<Item1>25</Item1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `preceding-sibling` [axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes), for example like this:

```
not(preceding-sibling::Items[1]/Item1 = Item1)
```

Comment: Except that the items in the node-list generally aren't siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and think about this in terms of "iterations", instead think about how to select the correct nodes for the `for-each` in the first place. It looks like you want to process only Items elements whose `Item1` is not the same as its immediately preceding sibling in the input tree

```
<xsl:for-each select="Items[preceding-sibling::Items[1]/Item1 != Item1]">
```

If you want to make much progress with XSLT you need to stop thinking about procedural things like loops and assignments and instead learn to think functionally - how does the output I want relate to the input I'm starting from.

Comment: Except that the items in the node-list generally aren't siblings.